# Wemos D1 EEProm put/get not getting correct value

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, eeprom

Hey all I have the following code in my Arduino IDE:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

bool debuggin         = true;
int brightness        = 255;
int ambientLight      = 30;
struct RGBLA {
  uint8_t R;
  uint8_t G;
  uint8_t B;
  uint8_t L;
  uint8_t A;
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  EEPROM.begin(512);
  readSavedSettings();
  updateEEProm(255,255,255,200,35,true,false);
}

RGBLA readEEProm() {
  int addr = 0;
  RGBLA customVars;

  EEPROM.get(addr, customVars);
  return customVars;
}

void readSavedSettings() {
  RGBLA returnedVars = readEEProm();
  if (debuggin) { Serial.println("START readSavedSettings"); }

  if (returnedVars.A == 00 || returnedVars.A == 0) {
    if (debuggin) { Serial.println("'A' not found! Default 30"); }
  } else {
    ambientLight = returnedVars.A;
    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("'A' found! ");
      Serial.println(ambientLight);
    }
  }

  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 3/*strip.numPixels()*/; i++) {
    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("LED ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(" set to: R: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)returnedVars.R);
      Serial.print(", G: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)returnedVars.G);
      Serial.print(", B: ");
      Serial.println((uint8_t)returnedVars.B);
    }
  }

  if (debuggin) {
    Serial.println("Turned off RGB LEDS");
    Serial.println("END readSavedSettings");
  }
}

void updateEEProm(uint8_t R, 
                  uint8_t G, 
                  uint8_t B, 
                  uint8_t L, 
                  uint8_t A, 
                  bool saveRGBL,
                  bool saveA) {
  int addr = 0;
  RGBLA customVars;

  //Save old json before clearing EEProm
  EEPROM.get(addr, customVars);

  //Clear EEProm
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < EEPROM.length(); i++) {
    EEPROM.write(i, 0);
  }

  if (saveRGBL) {
    //Get A value so that we can save it the same value
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5));
    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("Old JSON:");
      Serial.print(" R: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.R);
      Serial.print(" G: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.G);
      Serial.print(" B: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.B);
      Serial.print(" L: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.L);
      Serial.print(" A: ");
      Serial.println((uint8_t)customVars.A);
    }

    root["R"] = (uint8_t)R;
    root["G"] = (uint8_t)G;
    root["B"] = (uint8_t)B;
    root["L"] = (uint8_t)L;
    root["A"] = (uint8_t)customVars.A;

    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("New JSON:");
      Serial.print(" R: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["R"]);
      Serial.print(" G: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["G"]);
      Serial.print(" B: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["B"]);
      Serial.print(" L: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["L"]);
      Serial.print(" A: ");
      Serial.println((uint8_t)root["A"]);
    }

    EEPROM.put(addr, root);
  }

  if (saveA) {
    //Get R,G,B,L values so that we can save it the same value
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5));
    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("Old JSON:");
      Serial.print(" R: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.R);
      Serial.print(" G: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.G);
      Serial.print(" B: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.B);
      Serial.print(" L: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)customVars.L);
      Serial.print(" A: ");
      Serial.println((uint8_t)customVars.A);
    }

    root["R"] = (uint8_t)customVars.R;
    root["G"] = (uint8_t)customVars.G;
    root["B"] = (uint8_t)customVars.B;
    root["L"] = (uint8_t)customVars.L;
    root["A"] = (uint8_t)A;

    if (debuggin) {
      Serial.print("New JSON:");
      Serial.print(" R: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["R"]);
      Serial.print(" G: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["G"]);
      Serial.print(" B: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["B"]);
      Serial.print(" L: ");
      Serial.print((uint8_t)root["L"]);
      Serial.print(" A: ");
      Serial.println((uint8_t)root["A"]);
    }

    EEPROM.put(addr, root);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

And this is the output of that code:

```
START readSavedSettings
'A' found! 96
LED 0 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 1 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 2 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
Turned off RGB LEDS
END readSavedSettings
Old JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 96
New JSON: R: 255  G: 255 B: 255 L: 200  A: 96
Old JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 160
New JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 35
```

Now when I reset it this is the output:

```
⸮dOX⸮,R⸮X⸮4xC⸮⸮⸮START readSavedSettings
'A' found! 96
LED 0 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 1 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 2 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
Turned off RGB LEDS
END readSavedSettings
Old JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 96
New JSON: R: 255  G: 255 B: 255 L: 200  A: 96
Old JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 160
New JSON: R: 48   G: 255 B: 255 L: 63   A: 35
```

How come the **Old JSON** has the **'L'** value as **63** again when it should be the **New JSON** value of **200**? Why did it not save it but saved all the others? Also, Why is **'R' 48** when it should be **255** like **G** and **B**?

Is there something wrong in my code?

**Update 1**

This is the output after adding .end() to it:

```
START readSavedSettings
'A' found! 160
LED 0 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 1 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
LED 2 set to: R: 48, G: 255, B: 255
Turned off RGB LEDS
END readSavedSettings
Old JSON: R: 48   G: 255  B: 255  L: 63 A: 160
New JSON: R: 255  G: 255  B: 255  L: 200 A: 160
Old JSON: R: 128  G: 12   B: 17   L: 17 A: 60
New JSON: R: 128  G: 12   B: 17   L: 17 A: 35
```

and the code i use:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  EEPROM.begin(512);
  readSavedSettings();
  updateEEProm(255,255,255,200,35,true,false); //Save all but 'A' value
  EEPROM.end();
  updateEEProm(255,255,255,200,35,false,true); //Save just 'A' value
  EEPROM.end();
}
```

Comment: you should try SPIFFS instead of EEPROM: ez file interface, 1-3MB of space, no slicing or delimiters needed....

Comment: @dandavis, true. the emulation library has one small advantage. it is not erased when you upload SPIFFS image

Comment: Why do you put the Json `root` to EEPROM at he end of updateEEProm?

Comment: @Juraj do you mean in the **.put()** part?

Comment: you read the RGBLA struct but you write the json to EEPROM. which is not suitable for EEPROM

Comment: @Juraj using **.put()** makes it compatible with strings which the JSON is in.

Comment: you write to EEPROM `root` and not `customVars`. but you read `customVars` and not json

Comment: @Juraj customVars are gathering whats currently in the EEProm. I then save the passed R,G,B,L values and put it into the root struct and save that as the new data for the EEProm.

Comment: root is not struct. it is a class to handle json. it can't be saved to EEPROM. and  if could, it could not be read into RGBLA

Answer (score 2):

The esp8266 EEPROM emulation library requires a commit() call to save the memory image of EEPROM to flash.

Add `EEPROM.commit();` or `EEPROM.end();` as last line in your `updateEEProm()` function. [Documentation link](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom):

Second problem is that you don't write the RGBLA struct to EEPROM, instead you try to write the variable `root`, which is an instance of class JsonObject. Class types can't be put into EEPROM.

Comment: So this works even when using **.put()**?

Comment: of course. all emulating functions work with the RAM image of the emulated EEPROM. commit() or end() writes the image to flash. begin() reads the image from flash to RAM.

Comment: Hum, even doing **updateEEProm(255,255,255,200,35,true,false); EEPROM.commit(); updateEEProm(255,255,255,200,35,false,true); EEPROM.commit();** still does not seem to save it?